# The Class which not found in a Hosting Web

Tags: laravel, hosting

I actually already finish my project on localhost:8000, but when I put my project in a hosting, then I run it, I got this error when I logged in. Anyone knows?

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/inJnd.png)Class 'App\Periode' not found

Comment: Did you copy the entire vendor folder, and run `composer dump-autoload`?

Comment: I did copy all, but I didn't run that komposer, should I?

Comment: Yes, you should.